# error: cannot find symbol PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, symbols

I keep getting the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?");
symbol: variable conn
location: class splitString
```

Here's the code I'm using

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

class splitString {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  //Connect to database
    try {
       Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); 
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database", "postgres", "pswd");
       if (con != null)
           System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
    } catch(Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }

    String word = "Apples";
    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?");
    st.setString(1, word);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

  }
}
```

I want to look up the word "Apples" in the database using the variable named "word".

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you have declared 'con' and not 'conn', moreover the scope of 'con' remains within try block.

Comment: Try to use IDE which would highlight these issues and you would be able solve those on your own without any help from others.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database", "postgres", "pswd");
```

to

```
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database", "postgres", "pswd");
```

and don't add `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); 
       Connection con=DriverManager...`  in try catch block.
hope it helps :)

Comment: Class.forName and DriverManager both (i think) need to be in a try catch, but the declaration of Connection should be outside the try to be visible (just to be clear ;) )

Comment: if you want both class.forName & Drivermanager in try-catch you can have them in it. but than you will need to define connection object con outside try-catch otherwise it won't recognize connection object at the time you using it. ( that is prepared st where you are getting error )

Comment: That's not for me, but I'm saying that DriverManager.getConnection throws SQLException and Class.forName throws ClassNotFoundException, both need to be catch or throw back. And if one of those throw an exception, the connection won't be possible so no need to try to create a PreparedStatement on a null value.

Comment: so if i understood you well i think you want `class.forname` & `drivermanager` both in` try-catch` and if they do not throw any exception only in that case you want your `prepared stmt` to run. 
If thats the case you can use `nested try catch` block.  
`try { classForname & connection try { prepared st } catch { prepared stmt catch block} catch { class.Forname's catch block } }`

Comment: Wait, I don't want anything, I'm just giving you an advice for your answer ;) You CAN NOT remove both of those statement of the try catch because the Exception that MIGHT be thrown won't be catch or thown again.

Answer (score 0):

As say @Shail016 you have typo in name of `Connection`
Below fixed code with some additional try-catch blocks

```
package main;

import java.sql.*;

class splitString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Connect to database
        Connection con = null;
        String word = "Apples";

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database", "postgres", "pswd");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (con != null)
            System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
        else return;

        PreparedStatement st;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?");
            st.setString(1, word);
            rs = st.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody used the try-with-resource, this is how to do it with the autocloseable class. (If someone can test it on a Java 7 or greater, I work on 1.6 here...)

```
 try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

try(
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database", "postgres", "pswd");
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?");
){
    st.setString(1, word);
    try(rs = st.executeQuery();){
        //Read the resultset
    }
}
```

This will close the connectionm preparedStatement and the resultset automaticly after use. This is a good approch